# Can electroluminescence be theoretically used for RF communication?

Tags: solid-state-physics, radio-frequency

I know that photon energy of radio frequency, 3 kHz (1.24e-11 eV) to 3GHz (1.24e-3 eV), is much smaller than the thermal energy $k_B T$ at 300K (25.8e-3 eV), which in turn is much smaller than typical bandgaps. Does that mean that electroluminescene cannot ever be used for RF communication?

Comment: I'm having difficulty parsing what you are asking. Is it (1) is it conceivable for a solid-state luminescent (well, radio-escent) transition to be in the rf, or (2) can you use light for 'rf'-type communication (or LiFi as it is amusingly termed like it was a new concept)?

Comment: @JonCuster I meant your (1)

Comment: Doesn't it depend on your definition of "Radio" frequency? If you expect to detect the signal with a copper wire loop, the answer is probably "no". But bandgaps can be made to have really any size you want. A cooled device with such bandgap could be an RF emitter. And people use RF modulation of light lasers to achieve all kinds of effects...

Comment: Nothing stops you from mixing two mode locked optical frequencies down to the rf band, it's just an awfully complicated way of achieving something that can be done much easier (and better) otherwise.

Comment: @CuriousOne can you elaborate?

Comment: Take a non-linear optical material and mix $f_1$ and $f_2$ so you get $f_1-f_2$. Complicated, yes, will give you awful noise, indeed, but perfectly doable... there is no need to do it, though. We have very good methods to amplify and process radio frequencies without ever going the rout trough the optical. It seems to me that you are not quite sure how the band gap relates to the amplified frequencies in a semiconductor amplifier, though. Is that the actual question? The answer to that is that it doesn't for low enough frequencies.